# Munkres Example 14.2 - Dictionary Order

Tags: general-topology

I am going over Munkres' Topology. In Example 14.2 he says:

> Consider the set $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ in the dictionary order; we shall denote the general element of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ by $x \times y$, to avoid difficulty with notation. The set $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ has neither a largest nor a smallest element, so the order topology on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ has as basis the collection of all open intervals of the form $(a \times b, c \times d)$ for $a <c$, and for $a=c$ and $b<d$.

I have a few questions about this example. To clarify, is he saying if $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are basis of $\mathbb{R}$ then we can denote $(a,b)=x$ and $(c,d)=y$ so we can show $(a,b) \times (c,d)$ a basis for $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ as $x \times y$?

Another point of confusion for me is that when I see $(a,b) \times(c,d)$, I think of Caretsian Products and I picture a rectangle in my mind. However, he talks about $(a \times b, c \times d)$. Of course in this sense, $a \times b$ and $c \times d$ will just be points and he draw lines between these two points. For instance if $a=1, b=2, c=3 \text{ and } d=4$, we get the following picture:

[image]

which is different from the usual Cartesian Product. Could you please explain if there is any connection between Cartesian Products and order topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: No, I think you are getting confused by notation. At the beginning of the paragraph, Munkres adopts a slight abuse of notation by notating $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ as $x\times y$. Note that this is NOT a cartesian product (unless you want to look at it as the sole element of $\{x\}\times\{y\}$, but that's pedantic). So, by the set $(a\times b,c\times d)$, he means the collection of all elements $z\in\mathbb R^2$ such that under the dictionary ordering, $a\times b<z<c\times d$. And sets of this form are a basis for $\mathbb R^2$'s topology under the order topology.

Comment: TL;DR: There is no useful notion of order topology (that I know of) that lends itself well to be expressed in terms of cartesian products, at least in the way you've presented.

Comment: I think this is a very confusing notation then. I am not sure if this is the right question, but then in this sense, each $x$ and $y$ are not a basis of $\mathbb{R}$ but $x \times y$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, correct? And I should think of $x$ as a point not an interval. The same goes for $y$.

Comment: $x\times y$ is not a basis of $\mathbb R^2$. $x,y\in\mathbb R$. Please read the statements very carefully, I feel you are rushing through them. Munkres is very specific with the way he defines things, there should be no confusion with careful reading.

Comment: Then what is $x$? Is it an interval or a point?

Comment: I've written it several times, but it is an element of $\mathbb R$. So neither.

Comment: @Rob: It’s an abominable notation, but if you’re using Munkres, you simply have to get used to it. His $x\times y$ is just an ordered pair, a single point in the Cartesian product $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think I am starting to understand this more clearly. So when he writes $(a \times b, c \times d)$ he really means $((a,b),(c,d))$ where $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are not intervals but points of $\mathbb{R}^2$. That's why he suggests to write $(a,b)$ as $a \times b$. Am I getting this correct this time?

Comment: @Rob: Yes, that’s right; Munkres chose this very non-standard way of distinguishing intervals from ordered pairs. I agree with him that the dual use of parentheses in the same expression is unfortunate, but I prefer to adopt a notation often used in set theory and $(\langle a,b\rangle,\langle c,d\rangle)$ for that same interval.

Comment: Thanks Brian M. Scott and Don Thousand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand my misconceptions now so I will try to answer my own question. I will explain Example 14.4, the set $X=\{1,2\} \times \mathbb{N}$ and assess whether the order topology is the discrete topology or not which hopefully explains my misunderstanding.

First let's see what is the discrete topology on $X$:

$$\mathcal{T} = \{\phi,\{(1,1)\},\{(1,2)\},...,\{(2,1)\},\{(2,2)\},...,\{(1,1),(1,2)\},...,X\}$$

Now in order topology all open intervals $(a,b)$ and $[a_0,b)$ are basis elements. Here we make note that the element $(1,1)$ is the smallest element of $X$.

How does an open interval look like? For instance $((1,1),(1,3))$ is an open interval in $X$. Here $(1,1)$ is not itself an open interval but rather a point. This confusion arises because $(a,b)$ can be interpreted as both a point and an interval. Here we refer to $(a,b)$ as a point. This is why Munkres suggest using $a \times b$ instead. So $(1,1)$ can be written as $1 \times 1$. Here, $1 \times 1$ should not be interpreted as a number but rather it is the point $(1,1)$. What is the interval $((1,1),(1,3))$ equal to? The set $\{(1,2)\}$.

If order topology is the discrete topology, then all the one point sets would be open, that is a requirement of discrete topology.

Indeed, majority of one-point sets are open in the order topology. Any one-point set in can be written as $((x,n-1),(x,n+1))$ or in Munkres' words $(x \times n-1, x \times n+1)$, except $\{(1,1)\}$ and $\{(2,1)\}$. For instance the set $\{(2,10)\}$ = $(2\times 9, 2 \times 11)$.

The one-point set $\{(1,1)\} = [1 \times 1, 1 \times 2)$ since $(1,1)$ is the smallest element.

The set $\{(2,1)\}$ is not open. If it was, we could have written it as $(1 \times n, 2 \times 2)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This implies $n$ is the greatest natural number which is a contradiction.

One might wonder what is the open interval $(1\times 1, 2 \times 2)$ equal to? Well

$$(1 \times 1, 2 \times 2) = \{(1,2),(1,3), ..., (2,1)\}$$

For this reason, the order topology on $X$ is not the discrete topology.

**In conclusion:**

- There is no connection between Cartesian Product and the order topology in the sense I was thinking.
- Munkres does not mean $(a,b)=x \text{ and } (c,d) = y$. He means $(a,b) = a \times b$ or $(x,y) = x \times y$. It was meant to distinguish between points and intervals. However, as Brian pointed out in comments one could write $(\langle a, b\rangle, \langle c,d \rangle )$ to avoid confusion. I personally think Munkres' notation is very confusing and I wish he had explained a bit more to clarify that.
- $(a,b)$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $((a,b),(c,d)) = (a \times b, c \times d)$ is a basis element.